# Conditionally count values in a pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object where I am trying to count the number of rows where a value for `TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA` is `> 30`. I can count the number of rows for each dataframe in the groupby object using:

```
import numpy as np

grouped = master_lsoa.groupby('lsoa11')

grouped.aggregate(np.count_nonzero).TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA
```

But how do I conditionally count rows where the value for `TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA` is greater than 30?

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need:

```
np.random.seed(6)

N = 15
master_lso = pd.DataFrame({'lsoa11': np.random.randint(4, size=N),
                           'TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA': np.random.choice([0,30,40,50], size=N)})
master_lso['lsoa11'] = 'a' + master_lso['lsoa11'].astype(str)
print (master_lso)
    TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA lsoa11
0                 40     a2
1                 50     a1
2                 30     a3
3                  0     a0
4                 40     a2
5                  0     a1
6                 30     a3
7                  0     a2
8                 40     a0
9                  0     a2
10                 0     a1
11                50     a1
12                50     a3
13                40     a1
14                30     a1
```

First filter rows by condition by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - it is faster before grouping, because less rows.

```
df = master_lso[master_lso['TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA'] > 30]
print (df)
    TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA lsoa11
0                 40     a2
1                 50     a1
4                 40     a2
8                 40     a0
11                50     a1
12                50     a3
13                40     a1
```

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('lsoa11')['TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA'].size().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df1)
  lsoa11  Count
0     a0      1
1     a1      3
2     a2      2
3     a3      1
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also construct a new column indicating where the condition is met and sum up like (stealing @jezrael's dataframe):

```
master_lso.assign(Large_Enough= lambda x:x["TOTAL_FLOOR_AREA"]>30)\
    .groupby('lsoa11')["Large_Enough"].sum().reset_index()
```

Note that `True`values are interpreted as 1. So the sum provides the corresponding count here.
The advantage over @jezrael's solution is that you can still sum up the total area per group

Comment: I don't know how to give it back to you ;)